# ERC20 Tokens - Decimals and resell

Tags: solidity, contract-design, tokens, erc-20, ropsten

I have just created an ERC20 Token; i set the decimal to 4 and bonus value to 1200 then i sent 0.3 ether to its contract address to purchase my new tokens. I received 36 quadrillion tokens in return and i don't understand why! before ETH network i have created a same contract at ROPSTEN testnet but with 18 decimals and i got 360 Tokens in return of 0.3 ether

I have these two questions: (a) what is the math here why i got quadrillions at network ETH?  (b) can i convert tokens back to ether as a sender or as a contract owner? if yes how?

i have also tried sending tokens from myetherwallet but it is showing 0 of my tokens but i can see tokens under my address at both etherscan and ethplorer.io

**contract code:**

```
    function constructorfunc() public {
        symbol = "TKN";
        name = "token name";
        decimals = 4;
        bonusEnds = now + 1 weeks;
        endDate = now + 7 weeks;

    }



  function () public payable {
        require(now >= startDate && now <= endDate);
        uint tokens;
        if (now <= bonusEnds) {
            tokens = msg.value * 1200;
        } else {
            tokens = msg.value * 1000;
        }
        balances[msg.sender] = safeAdd(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
        _totalSupply = safeAdd(_totalSupply, tokens);
        Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, tokens);
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
    }
```

other functions that i have added in my contract

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Total supply
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint) {
        return _totalSupply  - balances[address(0)];
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Get the token balance for account `tokenOwner`
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Transfer the balance from token owner's account to `to` account
    // - Owner's account must have sufficient balance to transfer
    // - 0 value transfers are allowed
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
        Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Token owner can approve for `spender` to transferFrom(...) `tokens`
    // from the token owner's account
    //
    // https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md
    // recommends that there are no checks for the approval double-spend attack
    // as this should be implemented in user interfaces
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        return true;
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Transfer `tokens` from the `from` account to the `to` account
    //
    // The calling account must already have sufficient tokens approve(...)-d
    // for spending from the `from` account and
    // - From account must have sufficient balance to transfer
    // - Spender must have sufficient allowance to transfer
    // - 0 value transfers are allowed
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[from] = safeSub(balances[from], tokens);
        allowed[from][msg.sender] = safeSub(allowed[from][msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
        Transfer(from, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the amount of tokens approved by the owner that can be
    // transferred to the spender's account
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public constant returns (uint remaining) {
        return allowed[tokenOwner][spender];
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Token owner can approve for `spender` to transferFrom(...) `tokens`
    // from the token owner's account. The `spender` contract function
    // `receiveApproval(...)` is then executed
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function approveAndCall(address spender, uint tokens, bytes data) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        ApproveAndCallFallBack(spender).receiveApproval(msg.sender, tokens, this, data);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Showing your code would really help in this situation. Can't specifically help if you don't provide anything. [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question.

Comment: posting code here in 5mins

Comment: question updated with code now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is the math here why i got quadrillions?

```
if (now <= bonusEnds) {
  tokens = msg.value * 1200;
} else {
  tokens = msg.value * 1000;
}
```

`msg.value` is in wei. By sending `0.3 ether`, you credited yourself with `300000000000000000 * 1200` tokens.

> can i convert tokens back to ether as a sender or as a contract owner?

You can do both, as long as the contract has enough ETH I suppose. You can include a simple function, for the owner only or not, which can be called and will convert `X tokens` into `Y ether` for a converting rate you define I suppose.

Comment: before ETH network i have created a same contract at ROPSTEN testnet but with 18 decimals and i got 360 Tokens in return of 0.3 ether

Comment: i have added more code in question, can you please have a look? can i transfer back eth to sender?

Comment: `0.3*(10**18)*1200` is your number. You divide it by `10**18` if you have 18 decimals, which gives you 360 tokens. If you use 4 decimals, you divide by `10**4` which gives you `3.6 * 10**16` tokens.

Comment: thanks i have accepted it as answer, can you please guide me how can i transfer back ethereums i don't want to lose my ethereums

Comment: Based on `owner.transfer(msg.value);`, it should send you back the ETH, no?

Comment: i want to exchange my 36 quadrillions tokens with ether

Comment: It's your contract, no? If so, the ETH was already sent back to you the moment you bought the tokens.

Comment: my bad, just checked i have now got the ETH at owner address :D thanks again